# OctoberCms viewing protected files

Tags: octobercms

How can I view **protected** file in OctoberCMS? Going to its link throws a 404 error. Is there any way to view, download or show the file?

I've uploaded the file like what the manual said:

```
public $attachOne = [
    'resume' => ['System\Models\File', 'public' => false]
];
```

Reference: https://octobercms.com/docs/database/attachments

Comment: can you share more info what does mean `protected file`,  how u upload it and what you have info to see it front-end .. file id or url etc ..

Comment: updated my question. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm, actually you can `not show` that file using `direct URL` as we know this is protected file. so it can not access directly from `URL`

So `proper way` is to `read file from disk` and `show it to user or allow user to download it`.

`October CMS` provides `elegant` way to do it `echo $file->output();`

First you need to have protected file `file ID` or `its relation`

Then you can `defined CMS page` with url `/show-file/:id` which will hold `logic` for showing file.

This page will accept `candidate id` as **id** and show his `resume` to `him/user or allow user to download it`.

> Now in that page `code section`

```
use YourPlugin\Models\Candidate;
function onStart() {    

    $candidateId = $this->param('id');

    // do some validation with $candidateId if you really want to show file or not , 
    // may be compare to current login user etc .. here    

    // if all ok then
    $candidate = Candidate::find($candidateId);
    echo $candidate->resume->output();
    exit();

}
```

`echo $candidate->resume->output();` will `add all necessary headers for file` 
**automatically** and user can view or download file

reference: author also refereed this thing https://octobercms.com/forum/post/download-file

if you find any issue please comment.

Comment: is `exit();` necessary?

Comment: this is actually what i've done, thank you for your time.

Comment: hmm its not necessary but still for making your mind think that it will not execute further ;), as i in `output()` method there is no `exit` so better we write it :) there is no harm so